# Is there a way to make this image binding more performant?

Tags: wpf, image, data-binding, datatemplate, itemtemplate

I am binding a list of 500 odd nicks to a list with a status image for each. The scrolling of the list is painfully slow, and so is flicking between tabs with different lists.

This is all caused by my recent change in which I added these images.

Is there a way to speed it up?

**My bitmaps (very small 16*16) :**

```
<BitmapImage x:Key="ActiveIcon" UriSource="/WPFClient;component/Images/active.png" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="IdleIcon" UriSource="/WPFClient;component/Images/idle.png" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="AwayIcon" UriSource="/WPFClient;component/Images/away.png" />
<BitmapImage x:Key="UnknownIcon" UriSource="/WPFClient;component/Images/unknown.png" />
```

**My List :**

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Users}">
   <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
     <DataTemplate>
       <DockPanel>
         <Image Source="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource UserStatusToIconConverter}}" Height="16" Width="16" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
         <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nick}" />
       </DockPanel>
     </DataTemplate>
   </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

**My converter :**

```
public class UserStatusToIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        string userStatus = value.ToString();
        string iconName = "UnknownIcon";

        switch (userStatus)
        {
            case "Active":
                iconName = "ActiveIcon";
                break;
            case "Idle":
                iconName = "IdleIcon";
                break;
            case "Away":
                iconName = "AwayIcon";
                break;
        }

        return iconName;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

NOTE: The code also DOES NOT work as it currently stands, no image is actually displayed. However I assume thats a minor detail somewhere.

Comment: Post your full XAML. It sounds to me as if you're making the ListBox lose it's default Virtualization. Did you apply any Templates to the ListBox?

Comment: BTW no it's not a minor detail. You're doing a wrong Binding which causes a lot of Exceptions (you can see these in the Output Window). That's another probable reason for the performance drop.

Comment: @HighCore you are right. I will fix it and update the post.

Answer (score 1):

Try using VirtualizationStackPanel will give some improvements

```
<ListBox VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
                 VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">

</ListBox>
```

in framework 4.5 VirtualizingPanel is available and setting VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Item" will give good performance improvement

Comment: However VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling" is a useful tip. It says on MSDN "When an ItemsControl contains a many items, the process of creating and discarding item containers can negatively affect performance." -- how many is "many" would my 500 count?

Comment: @MuhammadA It will support for large number of items. 500 items won't make any performance issue

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve that is to change converter to:

```
public class UserStatusToIconConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private static readonly Uri ActiveIcon = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFClient;component/Images/active.png");
    private static readonly Uri IdleIcon = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFClient;component/Images/idle.png");
    private static readonly Uri AwayIcon = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFClient;component/Images/away.png");
    private static readonly Uri UnknownIcon = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/WPFClient;component/Images/unknown.png");

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var userStatus = value.ToString();
        switch (userStatus)
        {
            case "Active":
                return ActiveIcon;
            case "Idle":
                return IdleIcon;
            case "Away":
                return AwayIcon;
            default:
                return UnknownIcon;
        }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

The slow-down is caused by improper binding.